# Why scala compiler doesn't infer type with abstract type

Tags: scala, type-inference, path-dependent-type

Given the following code

```
trait A { type B }
case class C extends A { type B = String }
def f[V <: A](b: V#B => V) = b
```

This one compile

```
f[C](a => new C())
```

But why this one doesn't compile ?

```
f(a => new C())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it infers a type in one parameter list, then that constraint is used in subsequent param lists to the right.  (See many similar questions on SO.)

But nothing like that happens within a parameter list.

This doesn't work either:

```
scala> def g[V <: A](b: V => V#B) = b
g: [V <: A](b: V => V#B)V => V#B

scala> g((c: C) => "")
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("")
 required: ?#B
```

The `?` means it hasn't fixed `V`, even though it just solved for `V`.

Contrast:

```
scala> def k[V <: A](v: V)(f: V#B => V) = 42
k: [V <: A](v: V)(f: V#B => V)Int

scala> k(new C)(_ => new C)
res5: Int = 42
```

The current option to use is `-Ytyper-debug`.  Sometimes one can understand the output.

For your example `f(_ => new C)`, you can see it fail right away on the `x$1`, even though one wants it to backtrack and correct itself.

```
|    |    |    |    |-- ((x$1) => new C()) : pt=?#B => ? BYVALmode-EXPRmode-POLYmode (site: value res0  in $iw) 
<console>:11: error: missing parameter type
              f(_ => new C)
                ^
|    |    |    |    |    |-- new C() EXPRmode (site: value $anonfun in $iw) 
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- new C BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: value $anonfun in $iw) 
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- new C EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (silent: value $anonfun in $iw) 
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- C FUNmode-TYPEmode (silent: value $anonfun in $iw) 
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \-> C
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \-> C
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \-> ()C
|    |    |    |    |    |    \-> C
|    |    |    |    |    \-> <error> => C
|    |    |    |    solving for (V: ?V)
|    |    |    |    \-> C#B => C
```

There's also

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#local-type-inference

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that it's ambiguous whether to interpret your object as being of type `C` or `A`, since both are upper-bounded by `A`. I guess you could argue that the compiler should know that the latter doesn't completely make sense, since `B` is abstract within `A`. But I was able to get this to work, referring to `B` in `A` directly, instead of through `V`:

```
scala> trait A { type B }
defined trait A

scala> case class C() extends A { type B = String }
defined class C

scala> def f[V <: A](b: A#B => V) = b
f: [V <: A](b: A#B => V)A#B => V

scala> f(a => new C())
res0: A#B => C = <function1>
```

Comment: To be fair, you only asked why the bottom line doesn't compile.